# Nuxt.js using auth when multi proxy API

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I build Nuxt.js app with two APIs. I am using `@nuxtjs/axios`, `@nuxtjs/auth` and `@nuxtjs/proxy`.
At first I had only one API so I set `baseURL` in `nuxt.config.js` like this:

```
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
    //proxy: false
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'meta.token' },
          logout: { url: 'logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: 'user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data' }
        },
        // tokenRequired: true,
        // tokenType: 'bearer'
      }
    }
  }
```

Now I need to have 2 APIs URLs without losing the Auth strategies configuration. How Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a [new instance of axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) with a custom config for each API you want with a distinct `baseURL`.

```js
    var instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
    });
```

Comment: I think you can actually use nuxtjs axios with multiple proxies. I came here looking for a way to call different proxies: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options